Only one of two UPDATEs in CTEs is executed?
I have this situation where I have to use CTE's in this form
WITH
update_field_a AS (
update super_table SET
  a = ....
WHERE condition to update a hold true
RETURNING TRUE
),
update_field_b AS (
update super_table SET
  b = ....
WHERE condition to update b hold true
RETURNING TRUE
)
SELECT 
  (SELECT true FROM update_field_a) as updated_a,
  (SELECT true FROM update_field_b) as updated_b,

So basically two CTE's updating different fields of the same table with each having it's own update condition in the WHERE clause.
The problem is that the behaviour I am seeing is that only of of the CTE runs depending on which of the SELECT i call first in the last SELECT query.
That is given this
SELECT 
  (SELECT true FROM update_field_a) as updated_a, <-- first select
  (SELECT true FROM update_field_b) as updated_b,

The update_field_a CTE will run and update the table while update_field_b does not run because (SELECT true FROM update_field_a) as updated_a is called first.
But if I have:
SELECT 
  (SELECT true FROM update_field_b) as updated_b, <-- first select
  (SELECT true FROM update_field_a) as updated_a,

The update_field_b CTE will run and update the table while update_field_a does not run because (SELECT true FROM update_field_a) as updated_a is called first.
How can I ensure both CTE's run? I thought referencing them in the SELECT statement will trigger both of them, but for some strange reason it is only the first that get reference is the one that runs.
Note this query is part of a Rust application using the sqlx library. Update: I see the same behaviour if the query is executed directly in psql terminal, so the Rust/Sqlx details has no impact.

How can you be certain that only one of the updates actually ran?  Why are you putting an update statement into a CTE?  Why not just run the two updates directly, perhaps wrapped in a single transaction?

I am certain because I check the table in the database after the query runs. And unfortunately in this case I need to do everything in one query so cannot split into two. Note that the example above is a simplified version of the real query, hence there are other constraint that is enforcing this to be done in one query with CTEs

From which tool are you executing your Postgres SQL?  Are you doing this from the pg admin, from code, or somewhere else?

From code actually. Rust using sqlx. I'll update the question with this details

I crafted a simplified version of the query and executed directly in psql and got the same rbehaviour.

You mentioned you would include your Rust code...but that hasn't happened yet.

Why not just two simple UPDATE statements in a single transaction? Or a single UPDATE with a CASE condition about what to update? It would make it much simpler, and your problem will be gone.

Confirmed that it is the same behaviour when the query is ran directly in psql, so the Rust code is immaterial.

@FrankHeikens The OP is calling Postgres from Rust application code.  So I have asked to see the code so that I can suggest how to use a single transaction.

@FrankHeikens there are other constraints that this should be done in same query using CTE's. Plus this does not help explain the strange behaviour I am seeing, because in theory the CTE's I have should work fine, it is strange that it is the only one that get queried first that runs while the other one is ignored. I'll like to know why that is the case.


So I have asked to see the code so that I can suggest how to use a single transaction @FrankHeikens that would be besides the point :( and answering a totally different question. The question is not how to split this CTE into transactions,but an explanation for why the CTE's i have which in theory should work but exhibits the behaviour that the one that runs depends on the one that is referenced first in the last SELECT statement - and how to fix the CTE's not to do this


All CTEs and the main query see the same snapshot of underlying tables. Updating the same row multiple times does not work.

How can I ensure both CTE's run?

You cannot. Either split into two separate queries, or combine both updates into one. Like:
UPDATE super_table
SET    a = CASE WHEN condition_a THEN ... ELSE a END
     , b = CASE WHEN condition_b THEN ... ELSE b END
WHERE (condition_a OR condition_b)
RETURNING condition_a AS updated_a
        , condition_b AS updated_b;

Related:

SQL CTE Syntax to DELETE / INSERT rows

Are SELECT type queries the only type that can be nested?




All CTEs and the main query see the same snapshot of underlying tables. Updating the same row multiple times does not work. - But it does work for the first update. So still trying to understand how the fact that they all see the same snapshot ensures that the first one that is reference in the last select is the one that actually updates the snapshot


@FinlayWeber: That's just an implementation detail and not reliable. CTEs, though listed sequentially do not actually have an order. They can be executed in any arbitrary order - unless you chain them with a RETURNING clause. Then the first SELECT items happens to trigger its CTE first. The other one cannot update the same row again. But that's just how the query planner chooses to go about it. The 2nd link I added discusses a similar case.
